# Share images from my app that uses Universal Image Loader

Tags: android

In my app I'm using Universal Image Loader to view my images which their links saved as array of strings , I tried to modify ImagePager class to add Share button for images , but didn't work with me ??
I added Share button to Layout of Item_image_pager
and I wrote this code

```
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
              Uri.parse("images[position]"));

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));*/
        }
    });
```

but the following error appeared !!

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  java.lang.NullPointerException

I'm adding my share button in ImagePagerActivity
Universal Image Loader Code [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader)

Comment: Where it did appeared? And you need to provide more codes... You got a null in your code somewhere, but it can't be said according to this part that you shared...

Comment: I'm adding my share button in ImagePagerActivity, you can check Universal Image Loader Code [link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/example/universalimageloader)